# Destructing Props Multiple Times in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, react-props

When I find myself using the same `props` in a `react` `component` multiple times (e.g. within different methods on the component) I end up destructuring the `props` multiple times.

Is this bad practice? Should I be assigning the `prop` that is being destructured multiple times to the instance itself instead (something like `this.propOfInterest = this.props.propOfInterest` in the `constructor()`?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  myMethod() {
    const {
      propOfInterest,
    } = this.props

    // do something with propOfInterest
  }

  render() {
    const {
      propOfInterest,
    } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={propOfInterest}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Software Engineering would help you get answers on "best practice" questions.
thus I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs in "https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/"

Answer (score 2):

Destructuring is not a bad practice and it won't reduce the performance in any way. Under the hood, whether you destructure  or not, Babel will transpile your code into the same statement before bundling.

So basically,

```
const { propOfInterest } = this.props;
```

and

```
const propOfInterest = this.props.propOfInterest;
```

will be bundled in the same way.

If you copy these two line into the [online Babel transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl), you will get these results.

```
const { propOfInterest } = props;
const propInterest = props.propInterest;
```

will result in

```
var _props = props,
    propOfInterest = _props.propOfInterest;
var propInterest = props.propInterest;
```

Talking about performance, the moment you use `this`, it becomes an instance variable. And ideally instance variables are performance wise slower according to **Nicholas Zakas** in his book **High Performance JavaScript**.

> When it comes to Javascript data, there’s pretty much four ways to access it: literal values, variables, object properties, and array items. When thinking about optimization, literal values and variables perform about the same, and are significantly faster than object properties and array items.
>
> So whenever you reference an object property or array item multiple times, you can get a performance boost by defining a variable. (This applies to both reading and writing data.)

Drawing conclusions from the author's viewpoint, destructuring is a lot faster than storing the values in an instance variable.

If we could create a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) example, we will know for sure.